# How to make swipebox thumbnails appear in a grid instead of single column?

Tags: html, css

I am an amateur at web design and I am trying to make a group of 70 thumbnails appear in a grid, or columns, within a pre-existing design, helping out a friend.
At the moment they are in a single long column, is there a relatively simple way to change the layout?
here is the page:

```
www.mikehamiltonpaintings.com/gallery.html
```

and the css

```
www.mikehamiltonpaintings.com/css/main.css  
www.mikehamiltonpaintings.com/css/fixed_vert.css  
www.mikehamiltonpaintings.com/css/swipebox.css
```

and the js

```
www.mikehamiltonpaintings.com/js/jquery.swipebox.min.js  
www.mikehamiltonpaintings.com/js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js  
www.mikehamiltonpaintings.com/js/ios-orientationchange-fix.js
```

Any advice gratefully received!
Thanks :)

Comment: how many elements will be in a column of space?

Comment: Anything is better than single file! Say 4 for example .. and thanks for taking the time to look

Comment: ok. 4 elements in a column, and the row number is automatically chosed by CSS... correct, using `display: grid`?

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. URLS (which aren't even complete and linked) aren't adequate. You've bypassed the code requirement by formatting _them_ as code.

Answer (score 0):

just use `grid-template-columns` in your parent element to solve this!

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns

also using `1fr` as a metric, will be responsive... because will get the width of the parent element! (because I see that you have the image inside a div)

also for spacing DON'T add a `<p>` with a unicode char code...

 use **`gap`** instead

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap

```css
.container img {
  /* responsive image */
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.container {
  /* used css grid*/
  display: grid;
  /* always 4 images in a column, auto-generated rows*/
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  /* this is like margin */
  gap: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- dark -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/1dark.jpg" alt="dark windows 11">
  <!-- light -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/0light.jpg" alt="light windows 11">

  <!-- dark -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/1dark.jpg" alt="dark windows 11">
  <!-- light -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/0light.jpg" alt="light windows 11">

  <!-- dark -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/1dark.jpg" alt="dark windows 11">
  <!-- light -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/0light.jpg" alt="light windows 11">

  <!-- dark -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/1dark.jpg" alt="dark windows 11">
  <!-- light -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/0light.jpg" alt="light windows 11">

  <!-- dark -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/1dark.jpg" alt="dark windows 11">
  <!-- light -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/0light.jpg" alt="light windows 11">

  <!-- dark -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/1dark.jpg" alt="dark windows 11">
  <!-- light -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/0light.jpg" alt="light windows 11">

  <!-- dark -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/1dark.jpg" alt="dark windows 11">
  <!-- light -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/0light.jpg" alt="light windows 11">

  <!-- dark -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/1dark.jpg" alt="dark windows 11">
  <!-- light -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/0light.jpg" alt="light windows 11">

  <!-- dark -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/1dark.jpg" alt="dark windows 11">
  <!-- light -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/0light.jpg" alt="light windows 11">

  <!-- dark -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/1dark.jpg" alt="dark windows 11">
  <!-- light -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/0light.jpg" alt="light windows 11">

  <!-- dark -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/1dark.jpg" alt="dark windows 11">
  <!-- light -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/0light.jpg" alt="light windows 11">

  <!-- dark -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/1dark.jpg" alt="dark windows 11">
  <!-- light -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/0light.jpg" alt="light windows 11">

  <!-- dark -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/1dark.jpg" alt="dark windows 11">
  <!-- light -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/0light.jpg" alt="light windows 11">

  <!-- dark -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/1dark.jpg" alt="dark windows 11">
  <!-- light -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/0light.jpg" alt="light windows 11">

  <!-- dark -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/1dark.jpg" alt="dark windows 11">
  <!-- light -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/0light.jpg" alt="light windows 11">

  <!-- dark -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/1dark.jpg" alt="dark windows 11">
  <!-- light -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/0light.jpg" alt="light windows 11">

  <!-- dark -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/1dark.jpg" alt="dark windows 11">
  <!-- light -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/0light.jpg" alt="light windows 11">

  <!-- dark -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/1dark.jpg" alt="dark windows 11">
  <!-- light -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/0light.jpg" alt="light windows 11">

  <!-- dark -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/1dark.jpg" alt="dark windows 11">
  <!-- light -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/0light.jpg" alt="light windows 11">

  <!-- dark -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/1dark.jpg" alt="dark windows 11">
  <!-- light -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/0light.jpg" alt="light windows 11">

  <!-- dark -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/1dark.jpg" alt="dark windows 11">
  <!-- light -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/0light.jpg" alt="light windows 11">

  <!-- dark -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/1dark.jpg" alt="dark windows 11">
  <!-- light -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/0light.jpg" alt="light windows 11">

  <!-- dark -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/1dark.jpg" alt="dark windows 11">
  <!-- light -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/0light.jpg" alt="light windows 11">

  <!-- dark -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/1dark.jpg" alt="dark windows 11">
  <!-- light -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/0light.jpg" alt="light windows 11">

  <!-- dark -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/1dark.jpg" alt="dark windows 11">
  <!-- light -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/0light.jpg" alt="light windows 11">

  <!-- dark -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/1dark.jpg" alt="dark windows 11">
  <!-- light -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/0light.jpg" alt="light windows 11">

  <!-- dark -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/1dark.jpg" alt="dark windows 11">
  <!-- light -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/0light.jpg" alt="light windows 11">

  <!-- dark -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/1dark.jpg" alt="dark windows 11">
  <!-- light -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/0light.jpg" alt="light windows 11">

  <!-- dark -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/1dark.jpg" alt="dark windows 11">
  <!-- light -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/0light.jpg" alt="light windows 11">

  <!-- dark -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/1dark.jpg" alt="dark windows 11">
  <!-- light -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/0light.jpg" alt="light windows 11">

  <!-- dark -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/1dark.jpg" alt="dark windows 11">
  <!-- light -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/0light.jpg" alt="light windows 11">

  <!-- dark -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/1dark.jpg" alt="dark windows 11">
  <!-- light -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/0light.jpg" alt="light windows 11">

  <!-- dark -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/1dark.jpg" alt="dark windows 11">
  <!-- light -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/0light.jpg" alt="light windows 11">

  <!-- dark -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/1dark.jpg" alt="dark windows 11">
  <!-- light -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/0light.jpg" alt="light windows 11">

  <!-- dark -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/1dark.jpg" alt="dark windows 11">
  <!-- light -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/0light.jpg" alt="light windows 11">

  <!-- dark -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/1dark.jpg" alt="dark windows 11">
  <!-- light -->
  <img src="https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/0light.jpg" alt="light windows 11">
</div>
```